# IValidatableObject and Nullable value types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a struct that implements IValidatableObject, which I use for properties on a view model.  The validation works fine with non-nullable properties, but if add a property of type Nullable`<MyStruct`> the IValidatableObject.Validate method is never called for that property, even if it has a value.

Is there any way that I trigger the validation on my nullable properties too, or is IValidatableObject not intended to be used with value types?

Thanks

---

Additional information:

I wanted to be able to specify units when entering data in my form, e.g. 10m, 100km, 1cm etc.  I also wanted to validate that the entered data was within range and of a correct format.  My struct converts the string with potentially different units (100cm/100m/1km) into a decimal property which always has the same unit (1/100/1000) and vice-versa.

I used IValidatableObject for validation because the validation will always be the same for any instance of MyStruct - I didn't want to add an attribute each time it is used.

My model would look something like this:

```
public class MyModel 
{
    public MyStruct Ab {get; set;}
    public MyStruct? Cd {get; set;}
}
```

My view is a strongly typed view using the model, which renders my struct as a text box using a display template.  When the form is posted,  I have a custom model binder to convert the entered string back to my struct.

My controller action looks like:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

The model is bound ok for properties of type MyStruct and Nullable`<MyStruct`>.

Comment: Could you show us the code you have so far for your model, controller and view?

Comment: I've updated the question with more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible.

I dug into the MVC source.  In System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider there is the following code:

```
// Produce a validator if the type supports IValidatableObject
if (typeof(IValidatableObject).IsAssignableFrom(metadata.ModelType)) {
    //stuff
}
```

According to [this rejected bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/600344/type-isassignablefrom-handles-boxing-conversions-inconsistently), `Nullable<T>` cannot be assigned to an interface that `T` implements:

> "In short, a "DateTime?" value can be unboxed to a DateTime or an IFormattable value. But it cannot be assigned to a DateTime or IFormattable location."

Thus no validators are returned.

Looks like I will have to do this another way.